# Test Canvas Graphics with Selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to test canvas graphics with Selenium. Does anyone have any advice, resource to facilitate the development of the tests? Is it technically possible to test canvas with selenium?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254564/interacting-with-a-canvas-with-selenium

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible with selenium:
if look the selenium intro doc https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp:

**Test Automation for Web Applications**

Many, perhaps most, software applications today are written as web-based applications to be run in an Internet browser. The effectiveness of testing these applications varies widely among companies and organizations. In an era of highly interactive and responsive software processes where many organizations are using some form of Agile methodology, test automation is frequently becoming a requirement for software projects. Test automation is often the answer. Test automation means using a software tool to run repeatable tests against the application to be tested. For regression testing this provides that responsiveness.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to why it is not possible. There is no explicit mention regarding Canvas elements.