# Typing with Python

Tags: python, automation, keyboard, keyboard-events

I want to send keys to [this](https://www.typingclub.com/sportal/program-3/2958.play) link.

I have experimented with Selenium before and that was my first try. However, to do this I need to identify the HTML elements in order to send the keys. But they aren't available in this link, or at least I can't find them. I don't know much at all about web design, but I suspect stuff is hidden by JavaScript.

I want to use Python. How can I do this? I don't know if this is even possible, but I don't need to use a headless browser, I just want a working solution.

Comment: What have you tried? You can find the elements by right click-> inspect element on browser.

Comment: I can't find the elements that correspond to the balloons.

Comment: There is a canvas on which the ballons are loaded. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254564/interacting-with-a-canvas-with-selenium and this https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/